# How to release memory allocated in custom Constructor in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, swig

I have a memory-management question in SWIG.

I have this object in C++ (TestStruct.h):

```
struct Buffer {
    uint8_t* data;
    int length;
}
```

I want to be able to initialize this object using a python list or string and destroy it from python without memory leak.
my swig file is:

```
%module test

%newobject Buffer;
%nodefaultctor Buffer;
%nodefaultdtor Buffer;

%{
    #include "TestStruct.h"
%}

%include "TestStruct.h"

%extend Buffer {
    Buffer(PyObject* inputList)
    {
        int leng = (int)PySequence_Length(inputList);
        uint8_t* temp = new uint8_t[leng];
        cout << "Buffer Constructor called: " << leng << "  " << (unsigned int)temp << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<leng; i++){
            PyObject *o = PySequence_GetItem(inputList,i);
            if (PyNumber_Check(o)) {
                temp[i] = (uint8_t) PyLong_AsLong(o);
                //cout << "uint8_t to C++: " << (int)temp[i] << endl;
            } else {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Sequence elements must be integers");      
                return NULL;
            }
        }    
        Buffer* buff = new Buffer();
        buff->dataBuf = temp;
        buff->length = leng;
        return buff;
    }

    ~Buffer() {
        cout << "Buffer Destructor called: " << $self->length << "  " << (unsigned int)$self->dataBuf << endl;
        delete[] $self->dataBuf;
        delete $self;
    }
}
```

Running the simple test below sky-rockets the Python's memory usage to 30MB

```
import test
import sys
import time

times = 1000
printsteps = False
print("performing memory stress test")
for j in range(times):
    sizeBytes = 1024 * 1
    input_list = list(range(sizeBytes))
    buffer = test.Buffer(input_list)

    del buffer 
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

each time the loop is run, both the constructor and destructor are called (I validate that with printouts), but it won't solve the memory allocation problem.

I need the Buffer to pass it as an argument to another SWIG-wrapped function and I want to be able to create the Buffer's data using a python list. I tried using typemaps (in and freearg) with more or less the same code, but it failed. So I figured out to use custom constructors and destructors, but it won't solve the problem with memory leak. Any input welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the Python C-API in converting the Python list to a C++ `uint8_t[leng]` is incorrect and causing the memory leak. The point is that the function `PySequence_GetItem()` returns a *new reference* to the sequence item. Because you fail to call `Py_DECREF()` on that item, Python will not release the memory for that item when the list itself gets deleted.

To fix, you simply need to add `Py_DECREF(o);` in the for loop.

By the way, the line `del buffer` in the Python loop is superfluous.

Comment: One more note. If using multi-threading in C++, the inside of the for loop must be wrapped with `SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_BEGIN_BLOCK;` and `SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_END_BLOCK;` or else the program is going to crash at some point